# Decreasing File Size of Code

Tags: encoding, filesize

As a programmer, I've participated in various 1k competitions, which are where one must fit all of their code into 1kb. I was wondering if a way to help decrease file size would be to use a different encoding in the file that doesn't support unnecessary characters. For instance: utf8 supports a good deal of characters that I would never use, such as `ÿ`, `æ`, `Ø`, `¶`, and a good deal more. Is there any encoding method/type which is limited to basic programming characters? By basic characters, I mean a-z, 0-9, `()`, `{}`, `<>`, `+-*/=`, `.`, `?` along with everyday characters like `,`, `%`, etc. - really anything that's used in an everyday program without weird text such as the aforementioned characters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic encoding I can think of is ASCII - basically a 7-bit-encoding, but usually each character is stored in one byte. You can also use one of the ISO8859-family encodings that are still one byte per character but offer some more special characters - but those are depending on the specific codepage used.

But don't expect great savings - for all characters present in ASCII the utf-8 and the ASCII-encoding are exactly identical.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six-bit_character_code

The braille comes really close to what you mention.